# Aframe stereo component only showing left eye view

Tags: javascript, aframe, stereoscopy

Long time listener, first time caller!

I’m looking at Aframe to see if I can use it to display stereo photos through VR systems, such as Google Cardboard. I’m using the Aframe Stereo Component library to control each eye’s view so that the stereo photos resolve in 3D (think stereo viewer, or ViewMaster as the end goal of this endeavour). Because there is an unknown quantity of images (goal is to have it show various galleries of images), I am creating the photo elements on the fly using JavaScript.

The problem is that even though I am setting the stereo="eye:left" and  stereo="eye:right" attribute for the pictures, I am only seeing the left photo of the pair in both eyes. What I am expecting is for an element showing the left image to only display in the left eye, and the element showing the right image to only display in the right eye (that way, the stereo photo will resolve in 3D). You can test this to see if the images are being displayed correctly by changing the user agent of your browser to one of a phone (Safari does this in the developer menu), and clicking on the VR googles icon bottom right of the window.

When I use the Aframe inspector to check the scene, all the attributes appear to be correctly set and in the right locations, so it seems that my code is doing the job properly.

I am not sure if this is a problem with what I’m doing, or if there is a bug in the Aframe Stereo Component. Maybe I need to “kick” the code to see the scene fully constructed when the script has run somehow?

My (truncated but hopefully legible) code which shows the relevant functions:

```
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.4.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script src="aframe-stereo-component.js"></script>
<script>
// List of images to display
var images=["DSCF0189" , "DSCF0287" , "DSCF0469" , "DSCF0470" , "DSCF0471" , "DSCF0472" , "DSCF0473" , "DSCF0475" , "DSCF0477" , "DSCF0478" , "DSCF0479"];

AFRAME.registerComponent('on-load',
    {
        init: function ()
        {
            var sceneEl = this.el;
            setUpScene();
        }
    });

// This function creates the photo display element
function createImage( image , eye )
    {
        var cube = document.createElement("a-entity");
        cube.setAttribute('position', position + " 0 0.1");
        cube.setAttribute('material' , 'src: #' + image + eye);
        cube.addEventListener('click' , myHandleClick);     
        cube.setAttribute('mixin','picture');
        cube.dataset.id=i;

        myID = "picture" + image + eye;

        cube.setAttribute("id" , myID);

        return(cube);
    }
function setUpScene()
{
    var myPictures = document.querySelector('#pictures');
    var myAssets = document.querySelector('a-assets');
    numberOfFrames = images.length;
    position = 0;
    for (i=0; i<numberOfFrames; i++)
    {
        image = images[i];

        // Set up the image loader for the Right eye view
        var assetRight = document.createElement('img');
        assetRight.setAttribute('src', "images/" + image + 'R.jpg');
        assetRight.setAttribute('id' , image + 'R');
        myAssets.appendChild(assetRight);

        // Create the picture object for the image and
        // assign it to the right eye
        cubeR = createImage( image , 'R' , i );
        cubeR.setAttribute('stereo','eye:right');
        myPictures.appendChild(cubeR);

        // Set up the image loader for the Left eye view
        var assetLeft = document.createElement('img');
        assetLeft.setAttribute('src', "images/" + image + 'L.jpg');
        assetLeft.setAttribute('id' , image + 'L');
        myAssets.appendChild(assetLeft);

        // Create the picture object for the image and
        // assign it to the left eye
        cubeL = createImage( image , "L" , i );
        cubeL.setAttribute('stereo','eye:left');
        myPictures.appendChild(cubeL);
    }

}

</script>

<body>
    <a-scene on-load>

        <a-assets>
            <a-mixin id="picture" geometry="primitive:box; width: 12; height: 12; depth:0.1;" >
        </a-mixin>
        </a-assets>

        <a-sky color="#444"></a-sky>
        <a-entity id="pictures" position="0 0 -13"></a-entity>
    </a-scene>
</body>
```

Thanks!

Comment: More experimentation here indicates that showing just the left eye is wrong. If I add
    <a-entity geometry="primitive: box" material="color: #C03546" position="0 3 -10" stereo="eye:left"></a-entity>
      <a-entity geometry="primitive: box" material="color: #3546C0" position="0 5 -10" stereo="eye:right"></a-entity>

The cubes appear in BOTH eye views.

Comment: I believe that I have have solved this. For the camera, I was using <a-entity camera.... >...</a-entity>

By changing that to <a-camera .... >...</a-camera> the problem seemed to resolve itself.